# Inject Resolve Dependency to Every Controller in UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have ui router state like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('parent', {
  templateUrl: 'tpl/a.html',
  resolve: {
    resA: function() {
        return { 'value': 'A' };
    }
  },
  controller: function($scope, resA) {
    $scope.resA = resA.value;
  }
});
```

In the template html I use another controller (child controller). This child controller need resolve dependency from ui router state. But, it is not injected to child controller.

*tpl/a.html*

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
</div>
```

*ChildCtrl*

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, resA) {
   // some codes
});
```

I got an error, that resA unkonwn in ChildCtrl. How to inject resA in ChildCtrl?

Answer (score 2):

I see 3 options:

1) put the value in $scope of parent controller

```
   //it would be available in child controller in `$scope.a`
 $stateProvider.state('parent', {
  templateUrl: 'tpl/a.html',
  resolve: {
    resA: function() {
        return { 'value': 'A' };
    }
  },
  controller: function($scope, resA) {
    $scope.resA = resA.value;
  }
})
.state('parent.child', {
  templateUrl: 'tpl/child.html',
  controller: function($scope) {
    console.log($scope.resA) //'{value: "A"}'
  }
});
```

2) put child controller as controller for a sub-route, and resolve resA there as well

```
var a = { 'value': 'A' };
$stateProvider.state('parent', {
  templateUrl: 'tpl/a.html',
  resolve: {
    resA: function() {
        return  a;
    }
  },
  controller: function($scope, resA) {
    $scope.resA = resA.value;
  }
})
.state('parent.child', {
  templateUrl: 'tpl/child.html',
  resolve: {
    resA: function() {
        return a;
    }
  },
  controller: function($scope, resA) {
    $scope.resA = resA.value;
  }
});
```

3) make some service that will provide the data (that now is stored in resA) for controller and inject it to both controllers

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand in 2nd step. Can you add some of codes?

Comment: @windupurnomo, check the answer, I have put the example

Answer (score 0):

Checkout @BotanMan's answer.

Also another way, which is similar to the 3. answer.

Put your resource into a service.

```
var app = angular.module('app');
app.service('resA', function() {
   // your service here
});
```

And include it like so :

```
$stateProvider.state('parent', {
  templateUrl: 'tpl/a.html',
  resolve: {
    resA: 'resA' //your service name
  },
  controller: function($scope, resA) {
    $scope.resA = resA.value;
  }
});
```

So you can use that resource, like you intended :

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, resA) { //now it should work
   // some codes
});
```

See the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) on resolve.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @eenagy. My ChildCtrl is used in another state too. Is it oke resA work as dependency resolve and service too? I update my question...